# What does hash s indicate in lisp

Tags: print, read, defstruct

This is the result of 
    M-:  (elfeed-search-selected :ignore-region)

```
#s(elfeed-entry
    ("www.cbc.com.com" . "https://www.cbc.com.com/defg/Polyglot-programming_%7E017e364530a5359046?source=rss")
    "Polyglot programming - Abc"
    "https://www.cbc.com.com/defg/Polyglot-programming_%7E017e364530a5359046?source=rss"
    1530592564.0
    #s(elfeed-ref "07038fa7a0c9db39b71600a20fc065b1ea9e9a2d")
        html
        nil
        (ror unread)
        "https://www.cbc.com.com/ab/feed/defg/rss?q"
        nil))
```

`#s` appears twice. What does it indicate?

Is `(ror unread)` an array?

Why does this have a dot? `("www.cbc.com.com" . "https...")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. That is a [struct](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Structures.html) of `elfeed-entry` (defined by elfeed). The `#s` here means struct. The first one is for `elfeed-entry`, the second is for `elfeed-ref`.

   ```
   (cl-defstruct website name shortname url shorturl)

   (make-website :name "StackOverflow"
                 :url "https://stackoverflow.com/")
   ;; => #s(website "StackOverflow" nil "https://stackoverflow.com/" nil)
   (make-website :name "Youtube" :shortname "YT"
                 :url "youtube.com/" :shorturl "youtu.be")
   ;; => #s(website "Youtube" "YT" "youtube.com/" "youtu.be")
   ```
2. `#s` in the form of `#s((a . "a") (b . "b"))` indicates a [hash table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html#Hash-Tables). Also see [ErgoEmacs's document with code samples](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_hash_table.html).
3. The dot indicates a pair. `'("a" . "b")` means `(cons "a" "b")`. See [dotted pair notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dotted-Pair-Notation.html).

Relevant source code from elfeed: [`elfeed-entry`](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed/blob/02442cf9311af85173d27b313b1a3343933f44e0/elfeed-db.el#L93-L95), [`elfeed-ref`](https://github.com/skeeto/elfeed/blob/02442cf9311af85173d27b313b1a3343933f44e0/elfeed-db.el#L475-L476).